# How to pass command line arguments into gauge tests?

Tags: python, jenkins, command-line, gauge, getgauge

I want pass a command line argument `is_triggered=true` as part of running Jenkins gauge tests run.

How can I pass the argument when I am doing `gauge run specs --env TEST`?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but I think u can't.
What I am doing is to start with

```
gauge -Penv="keys"
```

and before I start the test I am writing in the env file my env:

```
echo -e is_triggered = true > env/keys/default.properties
```